# How to sort dictionary by pseudo-compound key?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
test = {}
test[(1,2)] = 1
test[(4,3)] = 1
test[(1,4)] = 1
```

How to sort by "pseudo compound key": first element of tuple and after second element of tuple ?

Answer (score 7):

```
test = {}
test[(1,2)] = 1
test[(4,3)] = 2
test[(1,4)] = 3

print sorted(test.iteritems())
```

Will give you:

```
[((1, 2), 1), ((1, 4), 3), ((4, 3), 2)]
```

If you want them back as a dictionary:

```
import OrderedDict
sorted_test = OrderedDict(sorted(test.iteritems()))
```

You've got a dictionary sorted by it's keys.

This all works because by default, tuples sort as you described.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries cannot be sorted by definition. What you can do is get the list of keys, sort it, and then refer to the dictionary in given order. For example:

```
test = {}
test[(1,2)] = 1
test[(4,3)] = 2
test[(1,4)] = 3

keys = sorted(test.keys()) # nothing fancy, default sort
for key in keys:
   print test[key]

>>> 1
>>> 3
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you want. If you want the keys of test sorted in that order, all you need is

```
sorted(test)
```

If you want the values of the sorted keys, then do

```
[test[key] for key in sorted(test)]
```